# MongoDB - aggregate average values and compare these to a fixed value, if these match return all related documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to return an overview of all documents where sensor = Barometer, and the average of the barometer values of all quests < 1013.

2 example documents in my collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("563aa5a57b93babedcb32133"),
"userId" : 5,
"questId" : 1,
"cacheId" : 1,
"date" : "11/3/2015",
"time" : "20:25",
"latitude" : 30.0482900000000010,
"longitude" : 110.4235900000000000,
"sensor" : "Geleidingsmeter",
"value" : 2808,
"loc" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        110.4235900000000000, 
        30.0482900000000010
    ]
}
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("563aa5a57b93babedcb321c5"),
"userId" : 1,
"questId" : 1,
"cacheId" : 1,
"date" : "11/3/2015",
"time" : "16:36",
"latitude" : 49.9738699999999980,
"longitude" : 16.3936099999999990,
"sensor" : "Barometer",
"value" : 1032,
"loc" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        16.3936099999999990, 
        49.9738699999999980
    ]
}
}
```

Now this is what I tried:

```
db.CacheWatch.aggregate([
{$match: {sensor: "Barometer"}},
{$group: {_id: {cache: "$cacheId", quest: "$questId"}, avgWeather: {$avg: "$value"}}},
{$match: {avgWeather: {$lt: 1013}}},
{$group: {_id: {user: "$userId", cache: "$cacheId", 
                quest: "$questId", sensor: "$sensor",
                value: "$value", loc: "$loc"}}}])
```

This totally doesn't work, but when I leave out the last group I do get all the average values per quest < 1013 which is good. But how do I return every document that belongs to these quests?

Comment: What exactly do you need? What is the problem definition? Can you give examples of expected output?

Comment: And please: what is a "weer "? Don't make it more difficult than necessary by using native language field names. Please use the edit button to correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with isn't what I had in mind at first, but I don't think that what I wanted to do was even possible.

This is what I came up with:

```
db.CacheWatch.aggregate([
{$match: {sensor: "Barometer"}},
{$group: {_id: {cache: "$cacheId", quest: "$questId"}, value: {$push: "$value"}, avgWeather: {$avg: "$value"}}},
{$match: {avgWeather: {$lt: 1013}}},
{$group: {_id: {cache: "$_id.cache", quest: "$_id.quest", value: "$value", avgWeather: "$avgWeather"}}}])
```

Which results in (only showing 1 result):

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "cache" : 2,
            "quest" : 10,
            "value" : [ 
                1031, 
                987, 
                985, 
                953, 
                1049, 
                1083, 
                952, 
                999, 
                1029, 
                1032, 
                982, 
                930, 
                1018, 
                989, 
                969, 
                909, 
                1012, 
                1123, 
                933, 
                1031, 
                913, 
                915, 
                1042, 
                899, 
                958, 
                948, 
                981, 
                949, 
                1022, 
                1029, 
                991, 
                902, 
                1033, 
                980, 
                933, 
                958, 
                1050, 
                970, 
                1026, 
                1014, 
                1001, 
                1078, 
                1105, 
                958, 
                948, 
                997, 
                1072, 
                1008, 
                1026, 
                1011, 
                962, 
                987, 
                1017, 
                1037, 
                981, 
                915, 
                949, 
                945, 
                1001, 
                1009, 
                997, 
                1024, 
                1066, 
                937, 
                914, 
                1075, 
                1016, 
                1015, 
                952, 
                1021, 
                936, 
                1062, 
                964, 
                1004, 
                1042, 
                982, 
                879, 
                1037, 
                1041, 
                945, 
                964, 
                1010, 
                984, 
                979, 
                1020, 
                1028, 
                1060, 
                962, 
                997, 
                954, 
                1040, 
                932, 
                1009, 
                1030, 
                1005, 
                1006, 
                1022, 
                965, 
                981, 
                968, 
                1035, 
                1052, 
                980, 
                968, 
                1026, 
                941, 
                1008, 
                1005, 
                933, 
                866, 
                1002, 
                944, 
                1020, 
                1065, 
                1052, 
                929, 
                1002, 
                963, 
                952, 
                928, 
                1006, 
                1110
            ],
            "avgWeather" : 992.8524590163934800
        }
    }
}
```

Now it returns every value that belongs to a particular quest with a quest average < 1013.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation is a pipeline. That is, each output of the previous stage is the input of the next stage. So let's dissect what happens here when applied to your sample data:

1. `{ $match: {sensor: "Barometer"} }`

   Of course, this returns only one document of your sample data:

   ```js
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("563aa5a57b93babedcb321c5"),
     "userId" : 1,
     "questId" : 1,
     "cacheId" : 1,
     "date" : "11/3/2015",
     "time" : "16:36",
     "latitude" : 49.97387,
     "longitude" : 16.39361,
     "sensor" : "Barometer",
     "value" : 1032,
     "loc" : {
       "type" : "Point",
         "coordinates" : [
           16.39361,
           49.97387
         ]
      }
    }
   ```
2. `{ $group: {_id: {cache: "$cacheId", quest: "$questId"}, avgWeer: {$avg: "$value"}}}`
   You modify the input document here, removing all but a few fields, adding only one. The return of this stage is

   ```js
   {
     "_id" : { "cache" : 1, "quest" : 1 },
     "avgWeer" : 1032
   }
   ```
3. `{$match: {avgWeer: {$lt: 1035}}}`

   Now with your sample data (please provide a [minimal, complete and **verifyable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time), your match on `avgWeer < 1013` does not match and document. For the sake of illustration, I set this value to 1035 and the returned document is

   ```js
   {
     "_id" : { "cache" : 1, "quest" : 1 },
     "avgWeer" : 1032
   }
   ```
4. `{$group: {_id: {user: "$userId", cache: "$cacheId", quest: "$questId", sensor: "$sensor", value: "$value", loc: "$loc"}}}`

   Compare the referenced fields with the document returned by the last stage. None of them exists in the referenced form, you could only reference the ids of the cache by using `"$_id.cache"` instead of `"$cacheId"` and the one of the "quest" by using `"$_id.quest"` instead of "$questId".

So, in order to solve this, you have to rework your first group stage so that it provides the data needed right away, and then only filter by the second `$match` stage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll be trying to fix the problem after the weekend because I have to study for a different exam this weekend.